# Symfony routing name through yaml

Tags: symfony, routes, annotations, yaml

Is it possible in Symfony 4 to set the routing name trough yaml.

So old annotation

```
/**
 * @Route("/cms", name="security_login")
 */
public function loginAction(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils) {
   // code here
}
```

Yaml annotation

```
login:
    path:       /cms
    controller: App\Controller\SecurityController::loginAction
    name: security_login
```

It looks like yaml doesn't support the name key. only the following keys are supported:

"resource", "type", "prefix", "path", "host", "schemes", "methods", "defaults", "requirements", "options", "condition", "controller".

or is the key 'login' the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the "login" key in your file is the route's name.
Click on the "YAML" tabs in [the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html) to see yaml examples :

```
# config/routes.yaml
blog_list:
    path:     /blog
    controller: App\Controller\BlogController::list

blog_show:
    path:     /blog/{slug}
    controller: App\Controller\BlogController::show
```

Corresponds to these annotations :

```
/**
 * Matches /blog exactly
 * @Route("/blog", name="blog_list")
 */
public function list()
{
    // ...
}

/**
 * Matches /blog/*
 * @Route("/blog/{slug}", name="blog_show")
 */
public function show($slug)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The name is specified in the yaml entry ...

```
security_login:
    path:       /cms
    controller: App\Controller\SecurityController::loginAction
```